# Clicking on a link-to without triggering parent element's action

Tags: ember.js

I have a very simple problem I couldn't find the solution to. What should I do to be able to click on the link without triggering the `open` action?

```
<div class="content-box" {{action 'open'}}>
  <!-- ... -->
  {{link-to 'content'}}
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

The action `open` is opening a modal and rendering it in the `application` template's `{{outlet modal}}`, so when I click on the link, I transition to `content`, but the modal still gets rendered.

I'm using Ember 1.5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the bubbles to false like:

```
{{#link-to 'content' bubbles=false}}New Content{{/link-to}}
```

Read more about Action Bubbling here: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_action-bubbling

Comment: Works! <3 I thought `bubbles=false` was the default behaviour.

Comment: How is this achieved in a <a href="#"> which gets dynamically generated ?